# Apply a 1D array to every cell of a 2D array to create a 3D array

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Given a 2D array and a 1D array in Numpy:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = np.array([2,4,6])
```

I'd like to subtract a - b but instead of getting:

```
Out[16]: 
array([[-1, -2, -3],
   [ 2,  1,  0]])
```

I want this instead:

```
array([[[-1, -3, -5], [0, -2, -4], [1, -1, -3]],
       [[2, 0, -2], [3, 1, -1], [4, 2, 0]]])
```

How do I do that vectorized (i.e. no for loops) for speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is

```
a[...,np.newaxis]-b
```

This is just a broadcasting trick.

Instead of subtracting from

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

you subtact from

```
>>> a[...,np.newaxis]
array([[[1],
        [2],
        [3]],

       [[4],
        [5],
        [6]]])
```

which has shape

```
>>> a[...,np.newaxis].shape
(2, 3, 1)
```

while `b` has shape

```
>>> b.shape
(3,)
```

So broadcasting rules will give you an output with shape `(2,3,3)` like you want. There is good information on the principles of broadcasting [here](https://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/operations.html#broadcasting).

Comment: Nice! Works perfectly!

Comment: Is there an equivalent trick to do the opposite: say take that 3D array and turn it back into a 2D array with each cell containing the totals so:

array([[-9, -6, -3],
       [[0, 3, 6]])

Comment: not sure I understand. you can post as another question if you like. I'm trying to get better at numpy

Comment: The answer is to use np.sum(c, axis=2)

Comment: What I really want to do then is divide the two. So c = a[...,np.newaxis] - b and d = np.sum(c,axis=2). So then I want e = c/d to normalize. But this doesn't work.

Comment: I think you just want `c/d[...,np.newaxis]`. not sure though

Comment: The general approach is to just use newaxis to make the shapes match dimensionally. Broadcasting fills in the empty axes

Answer (score 2):

You want [`outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) subtraction

```
>>> np.subtract.outer(a,b)

array([[[-1, -3, -5],
        [ 0, -2, -4],
        [ 1, -1, -3]],

       [[ 2,  0, -2],
        [ 3,  1, -1],
        [ 4,  2,  0]]])
```